# Spring Boot Integration Test using TestContainers: primary key violation on DB insert

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, integration-testing, testcontainers

During integration tests execution some of the test cases randomly fail with the error below. Sometimes test run finishes successfully with all green.

```java
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute batch; SQL [insert into "space" ("created_by", "created_date", "last_modified_by", "last_modified_date", "alias", "banner_text", "business_unit_id", "state", "id") values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)]; constraint [space_pkey]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute batch
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:276)

....

Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute batch
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:109)

....

Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: Batch entry 0 insert into "space" ("created_by", "created_date", "last_modified_by", "last_modified_date", "alias", "banner_text", "business_unit_id", "state", "id") values ('system', '2023-06-22 13:02:28.606027+00', 'system', '2023-06-22 13:02:28.606027+00', 'shouldDeleteSpaceWithGroups', NULL, 1, 0, 100092) was aborted: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "space_pkey"
  Detail: Key (id)=(100092) already exists.
  Location: File: nbtinsert.c, Routine: _bt_check_unique, Line: 534

...

Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "space_pkey"
  Detail: Key (id)=(100092) already exists.
  Location: File: nbtinsert.c, Routine: _bt_check_unique, Line: 534
  Server SQLState: 23505
```

The respected entity looks like:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString(callSuper = true, of = "alias")
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "space")
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public class Space extends AbstractAuditingEntity {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @NotNull
    @Column(name = "alias", nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String alias;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    @Column(name = "state", nullable = false)
    private EntityState state = EntityState.ENABLED;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "space")
    private Set<UserGroup> userGroups = new HashSet<>();

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "business_unit_id")
    private BusinessUnit businessUnit;
}
```

And the class it extends:

```java
@Getter
@Setter
@MappedSuperclass
@Audited
@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public abstract class AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public AbstractAuditingEntity() {
    }

    public AbstractAuditingEntity(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sequenceGenerator")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "sequenceGenerator", sequenceName = "hibernate_sequence")
    private Long id;

    @CreatedBy
    @Column(name = "created_by", nullable = false, length = 50, updatable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private String createdBy;

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "created_date", nullable = false, updatable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Instant createdDate = Instant.now();

    @LastModifiedBy
    @Column(name = "last_modified_by", length = 50)
    @JsonIgnore
    private String lastModifiedBy;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "last_modified_date")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Instant lastModifiedDate = Instant.now();
}
```

My setup:

1. I execute `Spring Boot`(2.7.3) integration tests using `TestContainers`(1.18.0) running `PostgreSQL`. `Hibernate` version 5.6.10.Final
2. About 20 test classes with 260 tests.
3. I enabled Spring Application Context DEBUG logging, and I see that 8 application contexts are cached.
4. Anotation I use on all integration test classes:

```java
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.TYPE)
@ActiveProfiles({"unittest", "non-async"})
@SpringBootTest(classes = TicApp.class)
public @interface TicIntegrationTest {
}
```

5. I also have a helper class which I use a lot to prepare db state for test cases. The error in 99% happens when executing `createSpace()` method. Class reduced version:

```java
public class RestHelper {

    private static final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    private final MockMvc mockMvc;

    static {
        objectMapper.findAndRegisterModules();
    }

    public RestHelper(MockMvc mockMvc) {
        this.mockMvc = mockMvc;
    }

    public SpaceHeaderDTO createSpace(String spaceAlias, String spaceName, HttpStatus expectedStatus) throws Exception {
        SpaceHeaderDTO spaceHeaderDTO = SpaceHeaderDTO.builder()
            .alias(spaceAlias)
            .name(spaceName)
            .admins(Collections.emptySet())
            .businessUnitId(1)
            .build();

        String jsonRequest = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(spaceHeaderDTO);
        String json = mockMvc.perform(post("/api/spaces", spaceHeaderDTO)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(jsonRequest))
            .andExpect(status().is(expectedStatus.value()))
            .andReturn().getResponse().getContentAsString();
        return parseJson(json, SpaceHeaderDTO.class, null, expectedStatus);
    }
}
```

At first I was thinking that the problem resides in Spring Application Context switching: a mismatch between DB state in TestContainers and the context. But when I set a debug point - I see that DB contains not all tests, but just a subset of them. So, I think it switches with the context.

I was trying to add `@BeforeAll/@AfterAll` annotation to each class in order to clean up DB by calling all `repositoryName.deleteAll()`. But in this case I started receiving errors that it tried to delete entity with ID which wasn't found in DB. So to say, the opposite error.

In what direction to look in order to solve this problem?